Django's update_or_create failing although kwargs is specified
I have the following Django model:
class Itens(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    itempr_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True) # This is NOT a relationship
    cod_item = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True)
    # Other fields...

As you can see, both itempr_id and cod_item are unique, so I specified update_and_create to take this into account:
class CreateItensSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Itens
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        item, created = Itens.objects.update_or_create(
            itempr_id=validated_data.get('itempr_id'),
            cod_item=validated_data.get('cod_item'),
            defaults=validated_data
        )

        return item

I call and save the serializer like this:
serializer = CreateItensSerializer(data=itens, many=True)
if serializer.is_valid():
       serializer.save()


However, whenever there is a duplicate, I get the following error:
{'itempr_id': [ErrorDetail(string='itens with this itempr id already exists.', code='unique')], 'cod_item': [ErrorDetail(string='itens with this cod item already exists.', code='unique')]}
I do not expect any uniqueness violation problems since the fields were already specified to be unique in the function call
How can I fix this?
EDIT: just to make it clear, this works if the DB's table is empty, there's no problem in the itens argument in serializer = CreateItensSerializer(data=itens, many=True)

You should remove cod_item and itempr_id  from validated_data before assign it to defauts try: itempr_id=validated_data.pop('itempr_id') and itempr_id=validated_data.pop('cod_item')

You did not make the combination unique, itempr_id and cod_item are in this modelling individually unique.

@willeM_VanOnsem yes, itempr_id and cod_item are individually unique, so, how should I tell to update_or_create this?

@JacekBBudzynski this way I keep getting the same problem, if I try to assign the other attributes (excluding these 2) to defaults nothing changes as well

@AkariOozora: no, since that would make it ambigous what record to update. Imagine you got already a record with itempr_id=42, and one with cod_item='A' (but not the same record), and you update or create one with 42 and 'A', then what record should be picked? Why use the first one and leave the others untoched?

I think the main issue is not that much the technical solution, more what making these fields unique means, and what updating the table means. It is quite strange that two or more fields are unique across a model.

In your modeling, you made both itempr_id and cod_item unique, yes. But these are individually unique. This means that if there is a record with itempr_id=42, then no other row can have itempr_id=42.
Your .update_or_create(…) [Django-doc] will update a row, if both the itempr_id and cod_item match. But this is thus something different. Indeed, if we update or create an item with itempr_id=42 and cod_item='A', and there is already a record with itempr_id=42, but with cod_item='B', it will try to create a new record, and therefore thus raise an error. If the fields are unique together, meaning that itempr_id=42 can occur multiple times, and cod_items='A' can occur multiple times, but the combination can occur at most once, then .update_or_create(…) would have worked.
The main issue is probably not that much technical, but more functional: if two or more columns are unique, and you work with .update_or_create(…), then which row should be picked to update in case of a collision? The one with the already existing itempr_id, or with the one with the already existing cod_items? Why the former over the latter?
If we would orient first on the itempr_id, we could work with:
def create(self, validated_data):
    updated = Itens.objects.filter(
        itempr_id=validated_data.get('itempr_id')
    ).update(**validated_data)
    if not updated:
        updated = Itens.objects.filter(
            cod_item=validated_data.get('cod_item'),
        ).update(**validated_data)
    if not updated:
        Item.objects.create(**validated_data)
    return item
which is essentially what .update_or_create(…) is doing, except that it uses the combination of the items to filter, although that might be a bit more efficient.
But if we use .update_or_create(…) to just silence integrity errors, that is likely caused by bad modeling: it is not very common that a model carries two or more (non-primary key) unique columns if these are unique individually. Typically the combination should be unique.
